# RXJS: Reduce stream and run through it again

Tags: typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

ich have the following Oberservable in RXJS.

```js
// this from() is an expensive database call, in my real scenario
const meal = from([
    { 
      "name": "white-bread",
      "type": "bread",
    },
    { 
      "name": "brown-bread",
      "type": "bread",
    },
    { 
      "name": "spelt-bread",
      "type": "bread",
    },
    { 
      "name": "cheese",
      "type": "spread",
      "connectedTo": "brown-bread",
    },
    { 
      "name": "jelly",
      "type": "spread",
      "connectedTo": "spelt-bread",
    },
])
```

I want to find all breads, that are not connected by any spread.
In this example,
`cheese` is connected to `brown-bread` and
`jelly` is connected to `spelt-bread`.
So I want to get `white-bread` as my result, because there is no `connectedTo` pointing to it.

My thought is, that I first have to reduce the stream, to get an array of all `connectedTo`:

```js
meal.pipe(reduce((acc, val) => {
   if (val.connectedTo) {
     acc.push(val.connectedTo);
   }
   return acc;
}, [])
```

Now I have a single array in my stream:

```js
["brown-bread", "spelt-bread"]
```

Now I want to run through the observable stream again, from the beginning, to filter the breads, to find my:

```js
{ 
   "name": "white-bread",
   "type": "bread",
},
```

I don't want to create the `meal` observable again, because it comes from an expensive database call.
Is there a way to run through the stream multiple times in order?
Or is there a totally other way to get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the whole stream into an array and then you can do any thing you want to the array with a map.

```js
const { from } = rxjs;
const { reduce, map } = rxjs.operators;

const meal = from([
    { 
      "name": "white-bread",
      "type": "bread",
    },
    { 
      "name": "brown-bread",
      "type": "bread",
    },
    { 
      "name": "spelt-bread",
      "type": "bread",
    },
    { 
      "name": "cheese",
      "type": "spread",
      "connectedTo": "brown-bread",
    },
    { 
      "name": "jelly",
      "type": "spread",
      "connectedTo": "spelt-bread",
    },
]);

meal.pipe(
  reduce((all, current) => { all.push(current); return all; }, []),
  map(all => all.filter(item => !item.connectedTo && !all.some(i => i.connectedTo === item.name)))
).subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe not the most "reactive" way, but works for me

Answer (score 1):

Tricky problem!  There may well be a simpler way to do this, but here is my solution:

```
meal.pipe(
  groupBy(val => val.connectedTo),
  mergeMap(group$ => group$.pipe(
    reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur], [`${group$.key}`])
  )),
  reduce((acc, cur) => acc.filter(item => item.name !== cur[0])),
  map(arr => arr.slice(1))
).subscribe(
  result => console.log(result)
);
```

This chain starts by using `groupBy` to create a set of higher order observables grouped by `connectedTo`.  It then uses MergeMap and reduce to take all those higher order Observables and create an array of an array of objects, the first of which is a list of all items without any `connectedTo`, and then each subsequent array item is an array of items with each `connectedTo` item object from the original `meal`.

That is then fed into reduce, which filters the first array item's sub-objects (acc) to eliminate all the items which show up in any of the subsequent emissions.  That will produce the array of remaining items after the filter.  Slice off the first "undefined" array item, and what is left should be an array of all items (breads) which did NOT have any associated `connectedTo` item.

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-57997281?file=index.ts) of the results.  In that StackBlitz are commented out `tap`s that can give you insight into the chain as it is being transformed.

Comment: Thank you! This is working and an interesting idea! But I'll stay with the other answer, as it is easier to understand, although it is maybe not the super "reactive" way

Comment: Agreed - Adrian's answer is simpler, and simpler is usually better.  Especially when coming back to it later.  I'd suggest you mark his answer as correct.